# Issues when using rpc:// as a backend for celery application (while amqp:// backend works)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a simple celery application with two tasks, `a_func()` and `b_func()`.
After starting the celery worker, I am calling `a_func.apply_async()`, and `a_func`, when running on worker is calling `b_func.apply_async()`.

When using **'amqp://'** as a backend everything is working well.
However, when using **'rpc://'** as a backend, I am having problems.
I am trying to get the state and the return value of the tasks.
For the `a_func()` task, there is no problem. However for `b_func()` I am getting `state = 'PENDING'` forever, and `get()` is stuck forever.

I am using:
celery version 4.3.0.
rabbitmq version 3.5.7 as broker.
python 2.7.
ubuntu version 16.0.4 LTS.

Worker cmd:

```
celery -A celery_test worker --loglevel=inf
```

celery application:

```
app = Celery('my_app',
             backend='rpc://',
             broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost/celery',
             include=['tasks'])
```

a_func and b_func tasks:

```
@task
def a_func():
    print "A"
    b_func.apply_async()
    return "A"

@task
def b_func():
    print "B"
    return "B"
```

Comment: I found this [issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4084) on celery's GitHub which is exactly your issue.